# How do i add two time variables to each other?

Tags: jquery, variables, addition

I would like to add two time variables to each other. but the output is not what i want. Because when i set for example ：

```
starttimestatus = 13:00:00
endduur = 13:30:00
```

My endtimestatus will be => 13:13:30

Somehow it doesnt add the HH

```
  starttimestatus = $("#starttimestatus").val(),
 endduur = $("#endduur").val();
      endtimestatus = endduur + starttimestatus,
```

Comment: If you use + on strings you won't get a meaningful time value.
Convert the strings to date objects first

Comment: Add together? What is the expected result here `26:30:00` ?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want;)

Comment: But how do i convert this to a timeobject then? Im not that familiar with jquery

Comment: If the format will always be HH:mm:ss
new `Date(0,0,0,starttimestatus.split(':')[0],starttimestatus.split(':')[1],starttimestatus.split(':')[2],0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the times together

```
function goodTimes() {
    var arr = [];
    $.each(arguments, function() {
        $.each(this.split(':'), function(i) {
            arr[i] = arr[i] ? arr[i] + (+this) : +this;
        });
    })

    return arr.map(function(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n;
    }).join(':');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TjB28/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You need convert the times to seconds, add them, and format the result.

```
function toSeconds(s) {
  var p = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(p[0], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(p[1], 10) * 60 + parseInt(p[2], 10);
}

function fill(s, digits) {
  s = s.toString();
  while (s.length < digits) s = '0' + s;
  return s;
}

var sec = toSeconds(intime) + toSeconds(out);

var result =
  fill(Math.floor(sec / 3600), 2) + ':' +
  fill(Math.floor(sec / 60) % 60, 2) + ':' +
  fill(sec % 60, 2);
```

Refer to [fiddle for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/JLh6W/4/)